# How to restart Python 3.5 script with space in path in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to implement a function that can restart the Python script on demand. A loop in the main is not acceptable. **Both the Python executable and the script contain spaces.**

What I've tried:

```
python = sys.executable
os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

Fails because the path contain spaces: `C:\Program: can't open file 'Files': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

```
python = '"' + sys.executable + '"'
os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

It fails with

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Simply:

```
os.execl(python, python)
```

Fails as well.

I've also tried:

```
subprocess.run([python])
```

And fails with: `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`

```
subprocess.run(['"' + python + '"'])
subprocess.run(['""' + python + '""'])
```

Also fails...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please add in the question, what does `sys.executable` contain

Comment: I mean please add `print(repr(sys.executable))`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with Popen:

```
    python = sys.executable
    script = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    subprocess.Popen([python, script])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do end up needing to use os.execl the following should work

```
python = sys.executable
os.execl(python, '"' + python + '"', *sys.argv)
```

The quotes should solve any issues due to any spaces in the path.